# Safari Extension - Certificate

Tags: macos, safari, safari-extension

Currently I have extension for Chrome and FF. My extension only popup and loads a page in iframe.

I am trying to now to implement the same extension for Safari but I have two questions/issues:

1. Safari Extension Builder requires Safari Developer Certificate. Regarding to all tutorials this Certificate should be free. But looks it cost 100$/year. Am I mixing this certificate with something else because I cannot find any clear explanation. But if that's true, is there any way to create Safari extension without this certificate.
2. The issue which I have is that Safari Extensions doesn't allow iframe in popup(popover). Is there any way to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your first question, you can create and test your safari extension locally in your browser without any certificate.

You are going to need a certificate when you are ready to upload it to the store.